# What's a good alternative to NVidia's proprietary drivers for a GF119

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I have a Thinkpad T520 with switchable (Optimus) graphics. The integrated card is Intel, which works great, but won't drive a DVI monitor. The computer also have an NVidia GF119 (Quadro NVS 4200M) which I can set the computer to use full-time in the BIOS.

The problem is, the driver in nvidia-current is awful. It doesn't support xrandr or compositing extensions; I have to configure my monitors using its awful GUI app, then restart X server and hope for the best. Without the proprietary driver, Linux and X seem to be defaulting to a VGA display.

Is there an alternative way to use my Nvidia GPU without using its awful drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the open source nouveau drivers. Alternatively (a better solution in my opinion), you can use [bumblebee](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee) and run in the "nvidia optimus" BIOS mode. This will run the main X server on your intel card and allow you to run specific graphic-intensive apps on the nvidia card with a command called optirun. With or without bumblebee installed, there is a program called screenclone that will allow you to use the DisplayPort/DVI output from the intel card by copying data from the intel card to the nvidia card.

More information on the graphics setup can be found here:
http://zachstechnotes.blogspot.com/2012/01/tri-head-display-on-linux-thinkpad-w520.html
(the W520 is similar to the T520 except for the VGA output)

Instructions for screenclone can be found here:
http://zachstechnotes.blogspot.com/2012/04/post-title.html

Comment: Never did get the bumblebee / optirun method working, but I got the x server working, so that's good. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The nouveau drives [list your card as supported](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames) on their wiki under the code-name [NVC0](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames#NVC0) http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames

[YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/YMMV).  Let us know if the nouveu drives work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Latest driver is 302.07

**Added X driver support for RandR 1.2 and RandR 1.3. See "Support for the X Resize and Rotate Extension" in the README for details.**

Comment: That's good. Weird that it took so long. Still, their drivers are just too buggy. Considering returning laptop and asking Lenovo for one without nvidia. :(